# How to make HTTP request in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurlsession

I read [The Programming Language Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/) by Apple in iBooks, but cannot figure out how to make an HTTP request (something like cURL) in Swift. Do I need to import Obj-C classes or do I just need to import default libraries? Or is it not possible to make an HTTP request based on native Swift code?

Comment: Use URLSession ( GET, POST, DELETE METHODS ) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306950/6898523

Answer (score 659, accepted):

You can use `URL`, `URLRequest` and `URLSession` or `NSURLConnection` as you'd normally do in Objective-C. Note that for iOS 7.0 and later, `URLSession` is preferred.

### Using `URLSession`

Initialize a `URL` object and a `URLSessionDataTask` from `URLSession`. Then run the task with `resume()`.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}

task.resume()
```

### Using `NSURLConnection`

First, initialize a `URL` and a `URLRequest`:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Then, you can load the request asynchronously with:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

Or you can initialize an `NSURLConnection`:

```
let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate:nil, startImmediately: true)
```

Just make sure to set your delegate to something other than `nil` and use the delegate methods to work with the response and data received.

For more detail, check the [documentation for the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html)

### Testing on an Xcode playground

If you want to try this code on a Xcode playground, add `import PlaygroundSupport` to your playground, as well as the following call:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

This will allow you to use asynchronous code in playgrounds.

Comment: Don't waste your time on iOS 8 beta 2 in a playground as XCPlayground is not supported.  There is a clever and ugly way to wait if you want to try a hack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24058337/700206

Comment: How do you send POST data using NSURLSession?

Comment: Thanks for the info about using it in a playground!

Comment: This example fails at 6.1:

test.swift:5:57: error: value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in

Comment: Have same error as mcuadros. No solution until now ;(

Comment: Adding an exclamation mark fixes @mcuadros' error message ... .dataTaskWithURL(url!)

Comment: it fails on "data" on print (the first example) . value of optional NSData not unwrapped

Comment: Since Swift 3, you can drop all those `NS` prefixes.

Comment: Can you please fix the code snippets? Here is what works as of Swift 4 ```print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))```

Comment: NOTE re: playgrounds, if you're seeing a deprecation notice for XCPlayground, use this code instead:                                                                                   
import PlaygroundSupport;
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Comment: guys is it still possible to make an `HTTP` request? would it work if it is not `HTTPS`? thanks

Comment: For sending POST data using NSURLSession, see examples here: https://samwize.com/2019/06/21/simple-guide-to-urlsession-http-get-post-requests/

Comment: `URLSession` is the way to go, And is what [`Alamofire`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is using behind the scenes.

Answer (score 112):

Check Below Codes :

**1. SynchonousRequest**

**Swift 1.2**

```
    let urlPath: String = "YOUR_URL_HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil
    var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
    var err: NSError
    println(response)
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
    println("Synchronous\(jsonResult)")
```

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR_URL_HERE"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil


    do{

        let dataVal = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response)

            print(response)
            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    print("Synchronous\(jsonResult)")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



    }catch let error as NSError
    {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

**2.  AsynchonousRequest**

**Swift 1.2**

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR_URL_HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var err: NSError
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println("Asynchronous\(jsonResult)")
       })
```

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR_URL_HERE"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    })
```

**3. As usual URL connection**

**Swift 1.2**

```
    var dataVal = NSMutableData()
    let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
    connection.start()
```

Then

```
 func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.dataVal?.appendData(data)
}


func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
{
    var error: NSErrorPointer=nil

    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as NSDictionary

    println(jsonResult)



}
```

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
   var dataVal = NSMutableData()
    let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
    connection.start()
```

Then

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    dataVal.appendData(data)
}


func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
{

    do {
        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonResult)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

**4.  Asynchonous POST Request**

**Swift 1.2**

```
    let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
     var stringPost="deviceToken=123456" // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


        var err: NSError

        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")


        })
```

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let stringPost="deviceToken=123456" // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    })
```

**5.  Asynchonous GET Request**

**Swift 1.2**

```
    let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


        var err: NSError

        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")


        })
```

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    })
```

**6. Image(File) Upload**

**Swift 2.0 +**

```
  let mainURL = "YOUR_URL_HERE"

    let url = NSURL(string: mainURL)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let boundary = "78876565564454554547676"
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" // POST OR PUT What you want
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Test.jpeg")!, 1)





    var body = NSMutableData()

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    // Append your parameters

    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("PREMKUMAR\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("IOS_DEVELOPER\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    // Append your Image/File Data

    var imageNameval = "HELLO.jpg"

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_photo\"; filename=\"\(imageNameval)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(imageData!)
    body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.HTTPBody = body




    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            //handle error


        }
        else {




            let outputString : NSString = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("Response:\(outputString)")


        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 105):

Another option is the **Alamofire** lib that offers Chainable Request / Response methods.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

**Making a Request**

```
import Alamofire

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
```

**Response Handling**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
              print(request)
              print(response)
              print(error)
          }
```

Comment: I think that replying by suggesting an external lib, while the functionality is provided by the framework is not the right way to do it.

Comment: @turkishweb is right. Cezar's answer is more complete and doesn't use external libraries. That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Cezar's answer is outdated (since Swift 3) and the interface of Alamofire is *a lot* nicer than that of `URLSession` and consorts. Also, acceptance is not a measure of some abstract measure of goodness (let alone yours! ;) ) but of what helped the OP the most. (For "pure" solutions, there's SO Documentation!) If that was this answer, perfect -- it's not using first principles, but then that's not always the "right" solution, isn't it?

Comment: Swift 3     `Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)`

Comment: Please do not offer third-party libraries unless it is specifically asked for, as per SO guidelines

Comment: @Raphael We can comment the answer to update if it is outdated. As time goes by, this answer will get outdated when Alamofile release new (incompatible) version. As for *how* nicer the interface is, I would say it depends; some says “jQuery syntax is *a lot* nicer than native JavaScript” as well.

Comment: @AlecO Can you please point me towards a write-up of those guidelines?

Comment: @FranklinYu Comments are supposed to be ephemeral; ideally, answers would continuously be edited to reflect a _current_ solution, or at least make previously implicit assumptions explicit.

Comment: @Raphael I think I didn’t make it clear: I suggested comment to notify authors of the update, so authors would update the answers to make it a *current solution*. This is exactly what happened to the answer you mentioned: author did update the answer after your comment.

Comment: Much much much much much better than the standard way

Answer (score 53):

**Swift 4 and above Data Request using URLSession API**

```
   // create the URL
   let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")! //change the URL
        
   // create the session object 
   let session = URLSession.shared
        
   //Now create the URLRequest object using the URL object
   let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
   // create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
   let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            
       guard error == nil else {
           return
       }
            
       guard let data = data else {
           return
       }
            
      do {
         //create json object from data
         if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            print(json)
         }
      } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
   })

   task.resume()
```

**Swift 5 and above, Decodable and Result enum**

```
// NetworkError enum which covers all possible Network errors

enum NetworkError: Error {
    case badURL(String)
    case networkError(Error)
    case invalidData
    case jsonParsingError(DecodingError)
    case invalidStatusCode(Int)
    case unknown(Error)
 }

// dataRequest which sends request to given URL and convert to Decodable Object
func dataRequest<T: Decodable>(with url: String, objectType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
    
    // create the URL instance 
    guard let requestURL = URL(string: url) else {
       completion(.failure(APIError.badURL(url))
       return
    }
    
    // create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    // Now create the URLRequest object using the URL object
    let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60)
    
    // create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        
        // declare result type
    let result: Result<T, NetworkError>
    
    // defer the to call completion handler
    defer {
        completion(result)
    }
    
    if let error {
        result = .failure(.networkError(error))
        return
    }
    
    guard let data = data, !data.isEmpty else {
        result = .failure(.invalidData)
        return
    }
    
    do {
        // create decodable object from data
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(responseType.self, from: data)
        result = .success(responseObject)
    } catch let error as DecodingError {
        result = .failure(.jsonParsingError(error))
    } catch {
        result = .failure(.unknown(error))
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**example:**

// if we want to fetch todo from placeholder API, then we define the ToDo struct and call dataRequest and pass "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" string url.

```
struct ToDo: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let userId: Int
    let title: String
    let completed: Bool
    
}

dataRequest(with: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", objectType: ToDo.self) { (result: Result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let object):
        print(object)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

// this prints the result:

```
ToDo(id: 1, userId: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false)
```

Comment: How can it be adjusted to accept an array of objects?

Comment: @kirqe if you want to accept array in response then pass `objectType: [T].self`` here T confirms to Decodable protocol

Answer (score 22):

**Basic Swift 3+ Solution**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com") else { return }

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

  guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

  print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Your example is for **Swift 3**, so you should use `URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")` instead of `NSURL`

Comment: casting from URL to URL makes no sense `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)`

Comment: I get this error: `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

Comment: @YumYumYum Have you configured app transport security as per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Leo Dabus the variable url is of type URL?

Answer (score 19):

**Using URLSession** + **Swift 5**

Just adding to [cezar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016254/1371853), if you want to make web request using Apple's URLSession class, there are multiple way to do the task

1. Simple GET Request with URL
2. Simple GET Request with URL and Parameters
3. Simple GET Request with URL with Error Handlings
4. Simple POST Request with URL, Parameters with Error Handlings

---

**1. Simple GET Request with URL**

```
func simpleGetUrlRequest()
    {
        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print("The response is : ",String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            //print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as Any)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

> *Note* : *Make sure You must add "NSAppTransportSecurity" key in pList for **http** requests*

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

---

**2. Simple GET Request with URL and Parameters**

```
func simpleGetUrlWithParamRequest()
    {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=peace")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print("Client error!")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("Server error!")
                return
            }
            print("The Response is : ",response)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

---

**3. Simple GET Request with URL with Error Handlings**

```
func simpleGetUrlRequestWithErrorHandling()
    {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print("Client error!")
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("Server error!")
                return
            }
            
            guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                print("Wrong MIME type!")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print("The Response is : ",json)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

---

**4. Simple POST Request with URL, Parameters with Error Handlings.**

```
func simplePostRequestWithParamsAndErrorHandling(){
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/post")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        let parameters = ["username": "foo", "password": "123456"]
        
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print("Client error!")
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("Oops!! there is server error!")
                return
            }
            
            guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "application/json" else {
                print("response is not json")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print("The Response is : ",json)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Your suggestions are appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you use `var session = URLSession.shared` when you are not using it, but only overwriting the variable? Is it needed?

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3.0**

Through a small abstraction
https://github.com/daltoniam/swiftHTTP

Example

```
    do {
        let opt = try HTTP.GET("https://google.com")
        opt.start { response in
            if let err = response.error {
                print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return //also notify app of failure as needed
            }
            print("opt finished: \(response.description)")
            //print("data is: \(response.data)") access the response of the data with response.data
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a way to wait for the request to finish before showing the view? @AlexanderN

Comment: The question is about `HTTP` not `HTTPS`.

Answer (score 13):

### Details

- Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18), Swift 5.7

### Info.plist

[NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity)

Add to the info plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

---

> NetworkManagerable interface

```
import Foundation

// MARK: NetworkManagerable

protocol NetworkManagerable: AnyObject {
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    session: URLSession,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions,
                    completion: @escaping (Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError>) -> Void)
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    session: URLSession,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) async -> Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError>
   
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest,
                        session: URLSession,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<Value, NetworkManagerError>) -> Void) where Value: Codable
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest,
                        session: URLSession) async -> Result<Value, NetworkManagerError> where Value: Codable
}

extension NetworkManagerable {
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .mutableContainers,
                    completion: @escaping (Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError>) -> Void) {
        dictionary(from: request,
                   session: .shared,
                   jsonReadingOptions: jsonReadingOptions,
                   completion: completion)
    }
    
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .mutableContainers) async -> Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError> {
        await dictionary(from: request, session: .shared, jsonReadingOptions: jsonReadingOptions)
    }
    
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<Value, NetworkManagerError>) -> Void) where Value: Codable {
        codable(type, from: request, session: .shared, completion: completion)
    }
    
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest) async -> Result<Value, NetworkManagerError> where Value: Codable {
        await codable(type, from: request, session: .shared)
    }
}

// MARK: NetworkManager Errors

enum NetworkManagerError: Error {
    case dataTask(error: Error)
    case emptyData
    case jsonSerialization(error: Error)
    case castingError(value: Any, isNot: Any)
    case networkMangerIsNotExists
    case jsonDecoding(error: Error)
}
```

> NetworkManager

```
// MARK: NetworkManager

class NetworkManager {
    private func data(from request: URLRequest,
                      session: URLSession,
                      completion: @escaping (Result<Data, NetworkManagerError>) -> Void) {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(.dataTask(error: error)))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(.emptyData))
                return
            }
            completion(.success(data))
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

// MARK: NetworkManagerable

extension NetworkManager: NetworkManagerable { }


// MARK: Receive Codable

extension NetworkManager {
    private func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                                from data: Data) -> Result<Value, NetworkManagerError>
    where Value : Decodable, Value : Encodable {
        do {
            let codableValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)
            return .success(codableValue)
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.jsonDecoding(error: error))
        }
    }
    
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest,
                        session: URLSession,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<Value, NetworkManagerError>) -> Void)
    where Value : Decodable, Value : Encodable {
        data(from: request, session: session) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {
                completion(.failure(.networkMangerIsNotExists))
                return
            }
            switch result {
            case let .success(data):
                return completion(self.codable(type, from: data))
            case let .failure(error):
                return completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func codable<Value>(_ type: Value.Type,
                        from request: URLRequest,
                        session: URLSession) async -> Result<Value, NetworkManagerError> where Value : Decodable, Value : Encodable {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            return codable(type, from: data)
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.dataTask(error: error))
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Receive Dictionary

extension NetworkManager {
    
    private func dictionary(from data: Data,
                            jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) -> Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError> {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: jsonReadingOptions)
            guard let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] else {
                return .failure(.castingError(value: json, isNot: [String: Any].self))
            }
            return .success(dictionary)
            
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.jsonSerialization(error: error))
        }
    }
    
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    session: URLSession = .shared,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .mutableContainers,
                    completion: @escaping (Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError>) -> Void) {
        data(from: request, session: session) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {
                completion(.failure(.networkMangerIsNotExists))
                return
            }
            switch result {
            case let .success(data):
                return completion(self.dictionary(from: data, jsonReadingOptions: jsonReadingOptions))
            case let .failure(error):
                return completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func dictionary(from request: URLRequest,
                    session: URLSession,
                    jsonReadingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) async -> Result<[String: Any], NetworkManagerError> {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            return self.dictionary(from: data, jsonReadingOptions: jsonReadingOptions)
        } catch let error {
            return .failure(.dataTask(error: error))
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage example

```
struct ItunesElement: Codable {
    let artistName: String
}

struct ItunesResponse: Codable {
    let resultCount: Int
    let results: [ItunesElement]
}

private var networkManager: NetworkManagerable = NetworkManager()
let searchString = "matrix".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
let urlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchString)"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    networkManager.dictionary(from: request) { result in
        print(result)
    }
    networkManager.codable(ItunesResponse.self, from: request) { result in
        print(result)
    }
    Task {
        print(await networkManager.dictionary(from: request))
        print(await networkManager.codable(ItunesResponse.self, from: request))
    }
}
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: searchRequest?  term?  Where do they come from?

Comment: This is full sample of the request. `class func searchRequest(term: String, ...` is the sample of the downloading data from itunes.apple.com. This sample will search, so, I chose/invented `searchRequest` function name. `term` is part  "https://itunes.apple.com/search?" request. You can choose any names of your functions  which will describe your logic model.

Comment: Nice solution. I have changed the `closure` to return an enum with the cases `success` and `error`.

Answer (score 7):

I have done **HTTP** Request **Both** methods **GET** & **POST** with **JSON Parsing** this way:

on **viewDidLoad()**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    makeGetRequest()
    makePostRequest()

}

func makePostRequest(){

    let urlPath: String = "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var stringPost="firstName=James&lastName=Bond" // Key and Value

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.HTTPBody=data
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

         if (jsonResult != nil) {
            // Success
           println(jsonResult)

           let message = jsonResult["Message"] as! NSString

           println(message)
         }else {
            // Failed
            println("Failed")
        }

    })

}

func makeGetRequest(){
    var url : String = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.timeoutInterval = 60

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            // Success
            println(jsonResult)

            let dataArray = jsonResult["contacts"] as! NSArray;

            for item in dataArray { // loop through data items

                let obj = item as! NSDictionary

                for (key, value) in obj {

                    println("Key: \(key) - Value: \(value)")

                    let phone = obj["phone"] as! NSDictionary;

                    let mobile = phone["mobile"] as! NSString
                    println(mobile)
                    let home = phone["home"] as! NSString
                    println(home)
                    let office = phone["office"] as! NSString
                    println(office)
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Failed
            println("Failed")
        }

    })
}
```

**Done**

Comment: Cannot invoke 'sendAsynchronousRequest' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableURLRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue, completionHandler: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Answer (score 3):

> I am calling the json on login button click

```
@IBAction func loginClicked(sender : AnyObject) {

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: kLoginURL)) // Here, kLogin contains the Login API.

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.criteriaDic(), options: nil, error: &err) // This Line fills the web service with required parameters.
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var err1: NSError?
        var json2 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(strData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err1 ) as NSDictionary

        println("json2 :\(json2)")

        if(err) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            var success = json2["success"] as? Int
            println("Success: \(success)")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Here, I have made a seperate dictionary for the parameters.

```
var params = ["format":"json", "MobileType":"IOS","MIN":"f8d16d98ad12acdbbe1de647414495ec","UserName":emailTxtField.text,"PWD":passwordTxtField.text,"SigninVia":"SH"]as NSDictionary
    return params
}

// You can add your own sets of parameter here.
```

Answer (score 3):

KISS answer:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://google.com")!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this. So many lines of code in all the other answers just for a simple http request, insane...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Just](https://github.com/justhttp/Just), a `python-requests` style HTTP library.

Some example of sending HTTP request with Just:

```
// synchronous GET request with URL query a=1
let r = Just.get("https://httpbin.org/get", params:["a":1])

// asynchronous POST request with form value and file uploads
Just.post(
    "http://justiceleauge.org/member/register",
    data: ["username": "barryallen", "password":"ReverseF1ashSucks"],
    files: ["profile_photo": .URL(fileURLWithPath:"flash.jpeg", nil)]
) { (r)
    if (r.ok) { /* success! */ }
}
```

In both cases, the result of a request `r` can be accessed in ways similar to `python-request`:

```
r.ok            // is the response successful?
r.statusCode    // status code of response
r.content       // response body as NSData?
r.text          // response body as text?
r.json          // response body parsed by NSJSONSerielization
```

You can find more examples in this [playground](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JustHTTP/Just/master/Docs/QuickStart.zip)

Using this library in synchronous mode in a playground is the closest thing to cURL one can get in Swift.

Comment: It seems like this library is deprecated. No Swift 4 support and no one responds to open issues.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1.

**JSON POST** approach example. To check internet connection add Reachability.h & .m files from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

```
func yourFunctionName {
    //Check internet connection
    let networkReachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus:Int = (networkReachability?.currentReachabilityStatus())!.rawValue
    print(networkStatus)
    if networkStatus == NotReachable.rawValue {
        let msg = SharedClass.sharedInstance.noNetMsg//Message
        //Call alert from shared class
        SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, title: "", message: msg)
    } else {
        //Call spinner from shared class
        SharedClass.sharedInstance.activityIndicator(view: self.view)//Play spinner

        let parameters = "Your parameters here"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        print("URL : \(request)")

        request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
            //Stop spinner
            SharedClass.sharedInstance.stopActivityIndicator() //Stop spinner
            //Print error in alert
            SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, title: "", message: "\(String(describing: error!.localizedDescription))")
            return
            }

            SharedClass.sharedInstance.stopActivityIndicator() //Stop spinner

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            do {
                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
                print(response!)
                //Your code here                    
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

If you have interest to use this function in **SharedClass**

```
//My shared class
import UIKit
class SharedClass: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

func postRequestFunction(apiName: String , parameters: String, onCompletion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?, _ result: [String: Any]?)->()) {

    var URL =  "your URL here/index.php/***?"

    URL = URL.replacingOccurrences(of: "***", with: apiName)

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL)!)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    print("shared URL : \(request)")
    request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

    var returnRes:[String:Any] = [:]
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if let error = error {
            onCompletion(false, error, nil)
        } else {
            guard let data = data else {
                onCompletion(false, error, nil)
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                   returnRes = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String : Any]
                    onCompletion(true, nil, returnRes)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                   onCompletion(false, error, nil)
                }
            } else {
                onCompletion(false, error, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


private override init() {

}
```

And finally call this function like this....

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.postRequestFunction(apiName: "Your API name", parameters: parameters) { (success, error, result) in
    print(result!)
    if success {
        //Your code here
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are start to finish instructions to make an HTTP request with Swift on Linux.

First create a SwiftPM package

```sh
mkdir swift-http && cd swift-http && swift package init --type executable
```

Then replace the contents of `./Sources/swift-http/main.swift`
with the code below:

```swift
import Foundation
import FoundationNetworking

let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://numbersapi.com/42")!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? String(describing: error))
    sema.signal()
}.resume()

sema.wait()
```

Then run the code

```sh
swift run
```

Output example:

```
[6/6] Build complete!
42 is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
```

**Note:** the `DispatchSemaphore` is used so that our program doesn't exit before getting a response.

You could have also done something like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import FoundationNetworking

var done = false

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://numbersapi.com/42")!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? String(describing: error))
    done = true
}.resume()

while !done { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple Swift 2.0 approach to making a HTTP GET request

The HTTP request is asynchronous so you need a way to get the returned value from the HTTP Request. This approach uses Notifiers and is spread over two classes.

The example is to check the username and password for an identifier token using the website http://www.example.com/handler.php?do=CheckUserJson&json= That is the file is called handler.php and has a switch statement on the do parameter to get a RESTful approach.

In the viewDidLoad we setup the NotifierObserver, set up the json and make the call to the getHTTPRequest function. It will return to the function checkedUsernameAndPassword with the returned parameter from the http request.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // setup the Notification observer to catch the result of check username and password
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkedUsernameAndPassword:", name: CHECK_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD, object: nil)        
    let username = GlobalVariables.USER_NAME
    let password = GlobalVariables.PASSWORD
    // check username and password
    if let jsonString = Utility.checkUsernameAndPasswordJson(username, password:password){
        print("json string returned = \(jsonString)")
        let url = CHECKUSERJSON+jsonString
        // CHECKUSERJSON = http://www.example.com/handler.php?do=CheckUserJson&json=
        // jsonString = {\"username\":\"demo\",\"password\":\"demo\"}"
        // the php script handles a json request and returns a string identifier           
        Utility.getHTTPRequest(url,notifierId: CHECK_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD)
        // the returned identifier is sent to the checkedUsernaeAndPassword function when it becomes availabel.
    }
}
```

There are two static functions in Utility.swift first to encode the json and then to do the HTTP call.

```
    static func checkUsernameAndPasswordJson(username: String, password: String) -> String?{
    let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        para.setValue("demo", forKey: "username")
        para.setValue("demo", forKey: "password")
    let jsonData: NSData
    do{
        jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(para, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        return jsonString
    } catch _ {
        print ("UH OOO")
        return nil
    }
}
```

and the Http request

```
    static func getHTTPRequest (url:String , notifierId: String) -> Void{
    let urlString = url
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let safeURL = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    if let url = NSURL(string: safeURL){
        let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.timeoutInterval = 60
        let taskData = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (data != nil) {
                let result = NSString(data: data! , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                sendNotification (notifierId, message: String(result), num: 0)
            }else{
                  sendNotification (notifierId, message: String(UTF8String: nil), num: -1)                    }
        })
    taskData.resume()
    }else{
        print("bad urlString = \(urlString)")
    }
}
```

The sendNotification function completes the circle. Notice that in teh Observer there is a ":" at the end of the selector string. This allows the notification to carry a payload in userInfo. I give this  a String and an Int.

```
    static func sendNotification (key: String, message:String?, num: Int?){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
        key,
        object: nil,
        userInfo:   (["message": message!,
                      "num": "\(num!)"])
    )
}
```

Note that using HTTP is oldFashioned, prefer HTTPS see [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 1):

Update :- **Xcode 13.0 & Swift 5+**

**GET HTTP REQUEST**

```
let url = URL(string: "URL HERE")! //PUT Your URL
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let safeData = data,
                  let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  error == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking error
                      print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                      delegate?.onError(error!)
                      return
                  }
            
            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                return
            }
            
            let responseString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Response String = \(responseString)")
        }
        
        task.resume()
```

Comment: The question is about `HTTP` not `HTTPS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var post:NSString = "api=myposts&userid=\(uid)&page_no=0&limit_no=10"

    NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    var url1:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!

    var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url1)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

            let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("error") as NSInteger

            //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

            NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

            if(success == 0)
            {
                NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                self.dataArr = jsonData.valueForKey("data") as NSMutableArray
                self.table.reloadData()

            } else {

                NSLog("Login failed1");
                ZAActivityBar.showErrorWithStatus("error", forAction: "Action2")
            }

        } else {

            NSLog("Login failed2");
            ZAActivityBar.showErrorWithStatus("error", forAction: "Action2")

        }
    } else {

        NSLog("Login failed3");
        ZAActivityBar.showErrorWithStatus("error", forAction: "Action2")
}
```

it will help you surely

Answer (score 0):

//Here is an example that worked for me

//Swift function that post a request to a server with key values

```
func insertRecords()
{



    let usrID = txtID.text
    let checkin = lblInOut.text
    let comment = txtComment.text



    // The address of the web service
    let urlString = "http://your_url/checkInOut_post.php"

    // These are the keys that your are sending as part of the post request
    let keyValues = "id=\(usrID)&inout=\(checkin)&comment=\(comment)"




    // 1 - Create the session by getting the configuration and then
    //     creating the session

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)


    // 2 - Create the URL Object

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString){


        // 3 - Create the Request Object

        var request  = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // set the key values
        request.HTTPBody = keyValues.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


        // 4 - execute the request

        let taskData = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {

            (data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            println("\(data)")

            // 5 - Do something with the Data back

            if (data != nil) {

                // we got some data back
                println("\(data)")

                let result = NSString(data: data , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("\(result)")

                if result == "OK" {

                    let a = UIAlertView(title: "OK", message: "Attendece has been recorded", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

                    println("\(result)")

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


                    a.show()


                    }


                } else {
                  // display error and do something else

                }


            } else

            {   // we got an error
                println("Error getting stores :\(error.localizedDescription)")

            }


        })

        taskData.resume()



    }


}
```

PHP Code to get the key values

$empID = $_POST['id'];

$inOut = $_POST['inout'];

$comment = $_POST['comment'];

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple **Swift 4** example in a playground:

```
import UIKit
// run asynchronously in a playground
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// create a url
let url = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

// create a data task
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("there's a problem")
    }
    print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
}

//running the task w/ resume
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

For XCUITest to stop the test finishing before the async request completes use this (maybe reduce the 100 timeout):

```
func test_api() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42")!
    let exp = expectation(description: "Waiting for data")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        exp.fulfill()
    }
    task.resume()
    XCTWaiter.wait(for: [exp], timeout: 100)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

An example for a sample "GET" request is given below.

```
let urlString = "YOUR_GET_URL"
let yourURL = URL(string: urlstring)
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: yourURL) { (data, response, error) in
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
    print("json --- \(json)")
    }catch let err {
    print("err---\(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
   }
dataTask.resume()
```