# Parse JSON API in Swift

Tags: ios, json, api, swift

I Have a Web Server setup with an API that retrieves data from my database. It Returns JSON Data. I would like to be able to both GET and POST Data into my database from my iOS App. For example, Look up a persons name or login to the application. I'm a Beginner at this and any code or examples would help.

Thanks!

Blake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a detailed example of how to make HTTP calls (GET, POST, etc..) in swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift).

### From the link above,

You can use `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection` as you'd normally do in Objective-C. Note that for iOS 7.0 and later, `NSURLSession` is preferred.

### Using `NSURLSession`

Initialize an `NSURL` object and an `NSURLSessionDataTask` from `NSURLSession`. Then run the task with `resume()`.

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

For more detail, check the [documentation for the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html)