# How can I send POST data using NSURLSession using Swift?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift) good answer about how to make a HTTP request, I am using the next code

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myserver.com")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

but I can't get any information about how to send a value using POST by this way, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON data using NSURLSession in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036233/how-to-post-json-data-using-nsurlsession-in-swift)