# Swift Completion Handler Syntax

Tags: syntax, swift

This code is used to answer the question here:

[How to make an HTTP request in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift)

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

The docs for `dataTaskWithURL` say the following:

```
func dataTaskWithURL(_ url: NSURL,
   completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                              NSURLResponse!,
                              NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

So it appears the `{(data .... }` portion of the first code block is the completion handler. I come from a Java background where this would be expressed like so:

`dataTaskWithUrl(url, function(data, ....) { .... });`

Could someone explain why the completion handler is not the second argument in the method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Trailing Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_161):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and after)
>   the parentheses of the function call it supports