# Nested function in swift 3

Tags: swift, methods, syntax, swift3, alamofire

I was checking through the Alamofire documentation and found the below code

```
 Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)

if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)")
}
}
```

It seems as if the function is written as

```
Class.Function().Function{
}
```

Is this called a nested function? If so how would I create a simple nested function to know the syntax

Comment: That's just method chaining (also mentioned in the Alamofire Readme)

Comment: And for the trailing closure syntax, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127427/swift-completion-handler-syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a nested function but a chain of functions.

```
class Alamofire {
    static func request(_ url: String)->Request {
        //... code ...
        return aRequest
    }
}

class Request {
    func responseJson(completion: (response: Response)->()) {
        //code
    }
}
```

So this is what is happening.
The request function of Alamofire is returning a Request object which has the responseJson function that accepts a closure as parameter.

In swift if the closure parameter is the last one, the function call can be synthesized by removing the parameter name and define the closure as a function so to do

```
Alamofire.request("whatever").responseJson(completion: { (response) in 
    //whatever
})
```

is exactly the same as doing

```
Alamofire.request("whatever").responseJson(){ (response) in 
    //whatever
}
```

This is a trailing closure. You can find more info about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in the "Trailing Closure" paragraph.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's [Method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114234/swift-method-chaining) and last one is the syntax of trailing closures.

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed
>   around and used in your code.

```
    func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
}

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
    // closure's body goes here
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

For more information about closures read [it](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)