# HTTP Request Swift Error

Tags: http, swift

I am trying to perform an HTTP Request but I am getting the error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7d26e9b0 {NSURL=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl})

Here is my code:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl")
    var error: NSError?
    let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

    if (error != nil) {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println(html)
    }
```

Comment: Not sure...but this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift

Comment: Works for me in the swift REPL. Are you on mac/ios/repl? Do you have any other code affecting NSURL things?

Comment: I am on a Mac, I do not have any other things affecting it. I have discovered it works on other URL's but I am still interested as to why this fails. Could it be the SSL?

Comment: Other than the fact that Xcode (latest/6.1) prompts me to unwrap the variable ```url``` with a ```!``` before this compiles, and both ```error``` and ```html``` should be unwrapped when printing/using them, the code worked fine when I tested it

Answer (score 0):

You must [unwrap](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) `url` and change [encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings) to `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. This line becomes as follows:

```
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)
```