# How to construct a json object from list of class objects

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm looking on how to construct or create a son object from a list of class objects.

I have a Category class which look like :

```
class Category {

    var Code: Int?
    var Label: String?


    init(Code: Int, Label: String) {
        self.Code = Code
        self.Label = Int

    }
}
```

and then I have a list of category `var categories = [Category]()`

and then I append my list like this :

```
  categories.append(5,"Shoes")
```

How can I construct a json object which will look like this :

```
{
"List":[
{
"Code":"5",
"Label":"Shoes"
},

....
]
}
```

Comment: Consider using external framework like ObjectMapper for exampe https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: I would recommend using swiftyJSON. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

First of all we update your `Category` class.

```
class Category {

    var code: Int // this is no longer optional
    var label: String // this neither

    init(code: Int, label: String) {
        self.code = code
        self.label = label
    }

    var asDictionary : [String:AnyObject] {
        return ["Code": code, "Label": label]
    }
}
```

### Step 2

Now we create a list of categories

```
var categories = [
    Category(code: 0, label: "zero"),
    Category(code: 1, label: "one"),
    Category(code: 2, label: "two")
]
```

Then we transform them into a list of dictionaries

```
let list = categories.map { $0.asDictionary }
```

And finally let's create the json

```
let json = ["List":list]
```

That looks valid

```
NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(json) // true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how to convert it to JSON, the variable JSON is still a list

Comment: No the variable `json` is a dictionary [String:AnyObject] and it does represent a JSON. What type of object did you expect?

Comment: I want a json object that I can send within a post request

Comment: You can transform the Dictionary to NSData with NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654550/how-to-create-and-send-the-json-data-to-server-using-swift-language. Then you can perform a POST request.