# How to make a Http get and set httpHeader in Swift?

Tags: ios, http, swift

I have try to make a HTTP Get in Objective-C.

It use the `NSMutableURLRequest *request;` in `Objective-C`, and use `[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];` to select `GET` or `POST`.

And set the Header via following code:

```
[request setValue:@"Application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request addValue:@"Application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",USER_PWD] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

I reference the link [How to make an HTTP request in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift), and it only show the following code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

But it didn't select `Get` or `Post` , and it also didn't set the header.
**How to decide the Http method is `Get` or `Post`? and how to set the Header? in Swift**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Comment: It shoe the error like `Cannot assign to 'HTTP Method' in 'request'`.

Comment: you are using `NSMutableURLRequest`.?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case , what the different here between `swift` and `Objective-C` ? It seems use the similar code here...