# New iOS Safari Extension Api change headers

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-safari, safari-extension

I'm writing an extension for Safari on iOS with the new iOS 9 Safari Extension API.

Typically the Extensions are used to block urls depending on certain patterns.

How can I go about changing the headers on a request before they are sent?

Comment: Take a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814050/how-to-make-a-http-get-and-set-httpheader-in-swift

Comment: @milo526 My question relates to safari extensions

Comment: @Akshat were you able to find an answer to this?