# Swift 2, Parsing JSON, empty response

Tags: php, ios, swift

I recently made a single-screen web-based application using PHP and AJAX. I want to port this app to iOS, and have started to teach myself Swift. I had the application working perfectly in Swift 1, but since I updated to xCode 7.2 and Swift 2 so that I could try the app on my iPhone with iOS 9, the code was completely non-functional. From here, I have new code now, and as far as I can see, it should work, but I am getting an empty response. What is wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var username_textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var password_TextFieldOutlet: UITextField!


    @IBAction func password_TextFieldAction(sender: AnyObject) {


        let username = username_textField.text
        let password = password_TextFieldOutlet.text
        var urlRequest = "~~URL~~/login.php?username=\(username)&password=\(password)"



    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The idea is I was to get my data from the database and see if "success" (a boolean value in the db) returns 1 or 0. If it returns 1, then perform a segue to next page, if not, create an alert saying incorrect username and password.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But your code doesn't do it!! It is just initialising variables.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj I understand, I can't find a solution to make it work - I am saying I don't understand how to retrieve json data form the URL

Comment: what is your `password_TextFieldAction`? Is it a button clicked or touch up on textField ==

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift

Comment: @Lee it is an action when the text field ends on exit

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the url

   `let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")`
2. Create the request

   `let request = NSMutableUrlRequest(url: url!)`
3. Add data and request methods

   `request.HTTPMethod = "POST"`
   `request.HTTPBody = "username=\(username text.text!)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`
4. Send the connection

   ```
     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { 
        (response, data, error) -> Void in
    if data != nil && error == nil {
        if let response = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { 
             //here is where you now have your response 
        }
    })
   ```

Comment: It is recommended to use NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection.

Comment: @ryantxr the encoding sent from the php file is JSON though

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` or `AFNetworking` for networking requests. Following is an implementation using `NSURLConnection`.

I have implemented `LoginViewController` class for you.
Hook the following `loginButtonAction` to 'Login/SignIn/Done' button on your UI.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var username_textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password_TextFieldOutlet: UITextField!
@lazy var data = NSMutableData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    startConnection()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func startConnection(){
let username = username_textField.text
    let password = password_TextFieldOutlet.text
    let urlPath: String = "~~URL~~/login.php?username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func loginButtonAction(sender: UIButton!){
    startConnection()
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
//Here I am printing the results, you can check the results and based on response Bool you can perform segue to next view controller.
    println(jsonResult)

}
}
```

Comment: Can you send your code to rajchanchalkhatri@gmail.com? Let me fix it for u.