# IOS Application Fetch data fro MySql Database

Tags: java, ios, mysql, json

I'm practicing some IOS coding in Swift 2 which consists in an app fetching information from a MySQL database. 
However, I'm confused in the concept. So currently my idea of how to accomplish this is that somehow the IOS App connects to the Apache Tomcat. To be able to do this, I though about creating a Java application that connects to the MySql using JNDI. With this I fetch the data and store it in a JSON object.
However this is where I get stuck. Should I  return this object to the IOS application or store it in a text file or JSON file and have the IOS application read it from there?

If I had to return the object, how can I do this? I've looked around but most examples are fetching information from an API and currently I want to do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a PHP file to connect and retrieve data from MySQL, and then you call this file by swift.

You will find a useful information in the following link :
[How to make an HTTP request in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift)