# How can I get data from a database to my iOS app?

Tags: database, swift, swift2, xcode7

**I've designed my app in Xcode**

But , it doesn't have any data  ! And I want to get data from a database .

I don't know where to start ? And what should I use ?

```
*php , sql , json ?*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app needs to request data from the server, the easiest way would probably using a [http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift). You could either transfer the data in a json format, or just use the GET part of the HTTP Request.

You then need a simple API, written in any language the server can run, which will most likely be:

- python
- php
- ruby

The choice of the language is up to you, it depends on personal preference and how scalable your API needs to be. The API has to deal with the request parameters and do the database work accordingly - this is up to you to design. It then needs to send a response - you can use plain text but json would be easier to deal with, as you can parse it with any language.

The app can then take that data and display it. There are lots of tutorials on the internet, here's [a basic one](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/) I've found, it doesn't tell you how to build a proper API, but you'll learn how to get started.