# HTTP Requests in Swift 3

Tags: swift, httprequest, swift3

I am fairly new to Swift, and am trying to make an HTTP request. I tried many of the ideas [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift), but all caused errors when run in a playground; I believe this is because they are all in Swift 1.0-2.0.

How can I make an HTTP request in Swift *3*?

**Update** I tried the first solution presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016254/5700898) and, after completing Xcode's suggested "Fix-its" I encountered four errors:

[image]

Comment: when working with playground you need to wait for http response with
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Comment: @AliKıran Ok...but that doesn't solve my question!

Comment: it's just hint for testing asynchronous code in playground.And also if you provide what kind of errors encountering in question we will help you more.

Comment: @AliKiran I updated my question with what errors I encountered.

Comment: Thanks for solving this everyone! Each one of the three answers below works great.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code:

1. By default, your app cannot connect to insecure (i.e. HTTP) site. It's a feature called App Transport Security. You need to make an exception in your app's `Info.plist` file to connect to HTTP sites.
2. This: `dataTask(urlwith: ! as URL)`. What are you trying to unwrap with the exclamation mark (`!`)? What's the variable name?

A lot of class names have changed between Swift 2 and 3 so those answers you've found may not be applicable. Below is an example that connects to [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) to get your IP address:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/ip")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }

    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}

task.resume()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Love it! Perfect, and thanks for the tips (I did know the first one, and for the second one the weird exclamation point came from Xcode doing a bunch of weird fix-its including that one)!

Answer (score 14):

There's typo errors (no url variable in the call) in your code.

Anyway, in Swift 3 it's better to use the new URL struct and the URLSession class.

Also, XCPlayground is now PlaygroundSupport.

And no need to use NSString when String is available.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data,
        html = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(html)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

*Note: this is for Xcode 8 beta 2. On beta 1 you would have to do `shared()` instead of `shared`. If you're on iOS don't forget to `import UIKit`, but this code also works for OS X if you `import Cocoa` instead.*

Comment: Thanks! This totally works for me, but I can't accept it until you fix the two errors in the code: you'll need to add a () after `shared` on line 5 and add import UIKit to the beginning, even if that seems self-explanatory.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I would have accepted just Code Different was first...your answer is just as good! Somebody upvote this.

Comment: Eh, no problem. The accepted answer is ok - and you're free to choose the one you want anyway. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

In your error it seems url missing.Here bare simple api call to help you get started with.

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let url:URL = URL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
let session = URLSession.shared

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

let paramString = "data=Hello"
request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    (
    data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(dataString)

}

task.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Thank you! This code sample works great, it's just that I don't think my mistake was not including a URL.

Comment: @Rob thank you for code review i update my sample according to your feedback.By the way printing NSString give formatted output.But it doesn't make much sense