# Azure asp.net web api working fine now how do I get iOS talk to Azure web server?

Tags: ios, asp.net, swift, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am new to iOS.
I searched similar questions but couldn't find right answer for my situation.

I created asp.net web api (slected only web api option not selected MVC option)
But I made model Account and controller `AccountsController` which is an `ApiContoller`

in my AccountsController:

```
[Authorize]
// GET: api/Accounts
    public IQueryable<Account> GetAccounts()
    {
        return db.Accounts;
    }

    // GET: api/Accounts/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Account))]
    [Route("api/account/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAccount(int id)
    {
        Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
        if (account == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(account);
    }
```

And my Account model:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public decimal Rebate { get; set; }
    public decimal MemCom { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `http://tresmorewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts`

I get all lists of accounts.

How can I create simple ios app in swift that shows lists of Account table? **And after I inserted [Authorize] to AccountsController, I get error message `Authorization has been denied for this request` by same http GET request `http://tresmorewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts`**

How can I send http request with authorization..?

I guess anyone who read this question can POST to my server..??

If someone can lead me to this step.. I think I can get further..

Thank you very much!

Comment: So, it is hard to answer this question without seeing your code. But basically you should integrate your authorization method (based on which one you are using) to http headers. I think the easiest way is to use some library for this network operations. You may want to check Alamofire for this. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#authentication

Comment: Actually, please look at this post. Everything is working properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292793/http-requests-in-swift-3