# integrate google contacts into ios app (swift)?

Tags: swift, google-contacts-api

So I already have Google SignIn implemented properly - all I want to do now is to sign the user in and grab all of their contacts' information. However, there doesn't really seem to be proper documentation. I know that I have to query https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full, but I don't know where that query would go or how it would be structured. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163529/integrate-google-contacts-api-into-my-swift-3-app/54710237#54710237

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know where that query would go or how it would be structured. Any ideas?

This, `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`, is called an [HTTP request](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177). You will send a 'GET' request to the server and if successful, the server sends a response back.

One of many ways to do this is to use [XMLHttpRequest in Swift](https://www.example-code.com/swift/http_xmlHttpRequestVerbs.asp).

snippet:

```
// Prepare the HTTP request object:
let request = CkoHttpRequest()
request.Path = "/xmlEcho.asp"

// This example will use the "PUT" HTTP request method
// (also known as HTTP verb)
request.HttpVerb = "PUT"
request.ContentType = "text/xml"
request.Charset = "utf-8"
success = request.LoadBodyFromString(xmlStr, charset: "utf-8")
```

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift), you can also make use of these methods:

1. **Using NSURLSession**

   ```
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
       print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
   }

   task.resume()
   ```
2. **Using NSURLConnection**

First, initialize an NSURL and an NSURLRequest:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

Then, you can load the request asynchronously with:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

Or you can initialize an NSURLConnection:

```
let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate:nil, startImmediately: true)
```

This is a lot to absorb if it's your first time. Hope this helps.