# How do I create a new Google Sheet from Swift 2.2 using Google Sheets API V4?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to create a new google sheet using the Google Sheets API V4 and Swift 2.2. I am hoping to get a return object with the spreadsheetID. I would like to provide a title. My guess is that i am not formatting the URL parameter correctly. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

```
import GoogleAPIClient
import GTMOAuth2
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     private let kKeychainItemName = "Google Sheets API"

    private let kClientID = "blah-blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    private let scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
    private let service = GTLService()

...
...
...

 func createNewSheet() {
        print("Creating New Sheet ...\n")
        let baseUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets"
        let params = ["title": "NewSheet"]
        let fullUrl = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(baseUrl,queryParameters: params)

        service.fetchObjectWithURL(fullUrl,
                                   objectClass: GTLObject.self,
                                   delegate: self,
                                   didFinishSelector: #selector(ViewController.displayResultWithTicket2(_:finishedWithObject:error:))
        )
    }

    func displayResultWithTicket2(ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
                                 finishedWithObject object : GTLObject,
                                                    error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print(object)

        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To [add a new sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/sheet) in Sheetsv4, use:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate
```

URI request body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "addSheet": {
        "properties": {
          "title": "Deposits",
          "gridProperties": {
            "rowCount": 20,
            "columnCount": 12
          },
          "tabColor": {
            "red": 1.0,
            "green": 0.3,
            "blue": 0.4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**How to do this in Swift?**

Make use of HTTP requests like `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection`

*Using NSURLSession*

Initialize an NSURL object and an `NSURLSessionDataTask` from `NSURLSession`. Then run the task with `resume()`.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

Credits to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift) for that snippet.