# How can I make and connect a spreadsheet to my code using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an app that needs to record data in a Google Spreadsheet with `Swift`.

I'm just really uncertain how to actually get started! I set up the Google sheets `API` in the Google `API` console and in my cocoapods following the Quickstart provided by google. Google's libraries `GoogleAPIClientForREST` and `GTMOAuth2` are in my app and are ready to be used.

I basically just need to read and write to an existing spreadsheet but I do not know how to create the spreadsheet and refer to it so I can read and write to it as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO Amber. You are unfortunately asking the question in the wrong place since this is off-topic. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and maybe this can help you : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

Comment: I'll change the question around...please let me know after I make the edit if it is on topic.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided to the documentation ? If you tried it, what errors did you run into etc? Provide those answers and you should be cleared and it will be much easier to help you for those who read, I have retracted the off-topic flag anyways.

Comment: Found some threads for you too that might help you, probably more if you give it a search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979057/how-do-i-create-a-new-google-sheet-from-swift-2-2-using-google-sheets-api-v4  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810535/how-can-i-make-basic-writing-via-google-sheets-api . Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I want to read or write to a Google spreadsheet using the Sheets API, I refer to [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).

[Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)

The following spreadsheets.values.get request reads the values stored in the range Sheet1!A1:D5 and returns them in the response. Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5
```

[Basic Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing)

Starting with a new, blank spreadsheet, the following spreadsheets.values.update request will write the values to the range Sheet1!A1:D5. The ValueInputOption query parameter is required and determines if the values written will be parsed (for example, whether or not a string is converted into a date).

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

Here's the [iOS Swift Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) for your code reference.