# Using Google Places Web API to search for business and using results to make a phone call

Tags: swift, swift3, google-places-api

I'm working on a project, and I'm completely stuck.

I get the user's location using CLLocation and am able to get the place name using CLGeocoder, and using this I've constructed a URL to search the Google Places Web API.

My question is, how can I actually complete the search and return the top place result's phone number? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
let url: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=taxi+" + placeMark.locality!+"&key=" + self.GAPIKEY)
```

This is the URL I've come up in case that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is an HTTP GET on the URL to get the API results. Consult the following SO question for various ways to do that:

[How to make an HTTP request in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift)

The data returned will be a JSON document in the format described in the [Google Places API Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses). Look for the `formatted_phone_number` and/or `international_phone_number` fields. See [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) for how to parse the JSON string.