# How to automatically take photos on an IOS device with HTML5

Tags: ios, html, file, input, camera

After some research I discovered that this code would allow me to take a picture inside a website using HTML5:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to make the camera automatically take photos. For example, I want the website to take a photo from my IOS device every 2 seconds for a minute. Is this possible?

Comment: From a website thats not possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. Do you know if there is any other way I can do this? Maybe using javascript or another lanuage? @VictorGardart

Comment: Would be possible if you made an app

Comment: Hmm. I would prefer to use a website as I am controlling an Arduino from the server, but I will look into this. Do you know if it is possible to make web requests from an app?@ViktorGardart

Comment: Never mind, I seem to have found the answer in this stack overflow question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift) Thanks for your help! @ViktorGardart

Comment: It is, you could also build the app with something like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/ to make it easier :)