# Send Firebase Cloud Message with only client side code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ultimately I would like to send custom push notifications when a message is received like What's App. I've been reading the documentation about Firebase Cloud Messaging [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple). Essentially an HTTP POST request is sent to generate the notification.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : /topics/foo-bar",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message",
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this client side in Swift?

Comment: Hi Peter. In general, it is ***strongly advised*** not to send downstream messaging from the client app side in any platform, since when making the requests, you'll have to include your *Server Key* in your client app code. This exposes it to unauthorized users for exploitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [URLSession or URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016254/5430608) or third part libraries such as [Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738382/5430608).
By the way this is highly discouraged because in this way you'll have to hard code your server key in the client. You should consider to use the [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).