# Swift Firebase Functions ERROR: NSCocoaErrorDomain

Tags: swift, function, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I try to run a Firebase Function from Swift, I get an error saying:

*Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}*

This is the Firebase Function:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!")
})
```

This is my Swift code:

```
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("helloWorld").call { (result, error) in
  if error == nil {
    print("Success: \(result?.data)")
  } else {
    print(error.debugDescription)
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message *"JSON text did not start..."* means what it says. Make a string from the affected data, print it and check it out.

Comment: The 'result' variable is nil though...

Comment: Maybe the data to be sent must have a specific (JSON) format.

Comment: There's a difference between callable Cloud Functions and request cloud functions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159634/firebase-https-callable-ios-swift/51159789#51159789) and then refer to [Call Functions via HTTP Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) for some details as I think your wanting onCall not onRequest, then again maybe not but it's good info either way.

Comment: @Lunke any update on this? I've run into the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

You may see this error if you haven't specified the correct region on the client side. For example:

```
lazy var functions = Functions.functions(region: "europe-west1")
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Simple solution to a misleading error message!

Comment: Wow. Hours and hours. Missed `Note: To call a function running in any location other than the default us-central1, you must set the appropriate value at initialization. ` at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I used `http://localhost:5000` instead of the correct `http://localhost:5001`. The emulator by default emulates the hosted website at port `5000` and the functions at port `5001`.

I realized this by evaluating the response in `FIRFunctions.m#261`. It was the html of the hosted website which obviously cannot be parsed as json.

Answer (score 0):

`response.send("Hello from Firebase!")`

You are not returning a JSON TEXT here but you are returning a string.

You need to return something like

`response.send('{"message": "Hello from Firebase!"}')`