# firebase function converts integer to an object

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

iOS client calls function with the following params:

```
func buyTicket(contestId: String, points: Int) -> SignalProducer<Void, Error> {
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("myFunction").call([
        "userId": Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid,
        "points": points,
        "contestId": contestId
        
    ], completion: ...
```

Then at the beginning of the function I have this log

```
const userId = req.body.data.userId;
const contestId = req.body.data.contestId;
const points = req.body.data.points;

console.log(`myFunction called with userId: ${userId} contestId: ${contestId} points: ${points}`);
```

What gets printed is

> myFunction called with userId: BzoW5pWLbWRnd2UgjnTkfd3xfNf2 contestId: pBsQo0FHMyu4ay18dexy points: [object Object]

why is points converted to an object?
This is causing my function to crash when I try to pass points to `FieldValue.increment`

Comment: Instead of interpolating `points` into a string format, log points like this, to see a better string representation: `console.log(points)`

Comment: Also, please edit the question to show the entire cloud function.  It looks like you might be doing something else very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing a [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) implementation with an invocation of a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). The two types of functions are not the same, and not compatible.

To invoke a **HTTP function** from your app, you'll perform a regular HTTP request from your Swift code. So for example with [How do I make an HTTP request in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-in-swift)

If you want to keep your Swift code the same, you'll have to [implement your server-side as a Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). This means the declaration looks like:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  ...
});
```

And you get the parameters as `data.userId`, `data.points`, etc.